# Fail Repeat Transaction in SagePay with NOTAUTHED

Tags: opayo

I have code to successfully perform a REPEAT transaction against the SagePay test environment.

With this I can see that an "OK" result from https://test.sagepay.com/gateway/service/repeat.vsp is working.

But is there anyway to get SagePay to return a "NOTAUTHED" result so I can test cases where the customer cannot be billed again (maybe their account is out of funds)?

Comment: Anything you can do in the SagePay portal to disable/delete the user? Not ideal (especially for automated testing) but might be an option.

Comment: @DavidG: Portal doesn't even list the payments that have been put through (this maybe an issue with my test account: have requested more access). But will be enough if possible.

Comment: @DavidG: Now I've tried that: voiding the original transaction will fail the repeat. But as "INVALID" rather than "NOTAUTHED", so will work to a degree. So the question still stands…

Comment: Yeah, was worth a try. I've not done anything with repeat transactions so can't really help. I'd suggest SagePay support though, they are usually quite good at helping out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked SagePay support.

Their response:

> You can not get Test payments to fail other than not entering one of our dummy test cards

Ie. SagePay does not provide any mechanism for testing, for example, when a customer's card no longer has sufficient funds.

Comment: I had a feeling this might be the case. I guess the only thing you can do now is to manually modify the response from SagePay and set the status to `NOTAUTHED` :(

Answer (score 0):

The only way to test a declined payment due to insufficient funds is to manually modify the response from Sage Pay (Opayo) with the values it would return in a real scenario.

The values you can use are as follows:

**Status**

```
NOTAUTHED
```

**3DSecureStatus**

```
ATTEMPTONLY
```

**StatusDetail**

```
2000 : NOTAUTHED : The Authorisation was Declined by the bank.
```

---

[Opayo documentation about this error](https://www.opayo.co.uk/support/error-codes/2000-notauthed-authorisation-was-declined-bank)